# Is there any way to get data above a selected percentile?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sp as following to get a list of areacode(phone) and sales amount on a selected percentile. For example at 0.5. However, I don't only want to see the data at 0.5,I also want to see the data above 0.5(the selected parameter).How can I do with sql server coding?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Percentile1 @per real
AS
SELECT c.[area code],PERCENTILE_DISC(@per) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SalesAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY [area code]) AS percentileamount 
from (select SUBSTRING(s.phone,2,3) as [area code],sum(b.Salesamount) as SalesAmount from Orders a 
join (select OrderID, sum(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-Discount) ) as Salesamount from [Order Details] group by OrderID) as b
on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
join Shippers s
on a.ShipVia=s.ShipperID
group by s.Phone) c

exec SP_1 0.5
```

Comment: FYI the prefix ​`sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for ​**S**​pecial / ​**S**​ystem ​**P**​rocedures. It should ​*not*​ be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [​Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?​](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I have no idea why the formatting of that comment is so wonky...

Comment: Write the query in a derived table or cte..and get from that all salesamount >= percentile amount `select * from (SELECT c.[area code], SalesAmount, PERCENTILE_DISC(@per....) AS percentileamount ...group by s.Phone) c) as d where SalesAmount >= percentileamount`

Comment: Thanks for your reply， however this is not a query, it is a store procedure. I need to keep a parameter here in order to be selected as a specific percentile. With a selection of number of percentile, the report needs to return the data equal or above the given percentile.

Comment: Yes it is, @ROSIE , your procedure *contains* a query. A query being inside a procedure doesn't make it not a query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PERCENT_RANK` function for this. Place it inside the subquery and filter it afterwards.

> You should make good use of whitespace and formatting, it's free.
> Also, see [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Percentile1 @per real
AS

SELECT
  o.[area code],
  percentileamount
from (
    select
      SUBSTRING(s.phone, 2, 3) as [area code],
      sum(od.Salesamount) as SalesAmount,
      PERCENTILE_DISC(@per) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sum(od.Salesamount)) OVER (PARTITION BY [area code]) AS percentileamount,
      PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [area code] ORDER BY sum(od.Salesamount)) AS percentile
    from Orders o
    join (
        select
          OrderID,
          sum(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-Discount) ) as Salesamount
        from [Order Details]
        group by OrderID
    ) as od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    join Shippers s on o.ShipVia = s.ShipperID
    group by s.Phone
) o
where
  o.percentile >= @per;
```